# How to recover a discarded documentation draft after it had been submitted for review?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

I spent quite a while documenting something and submitted it for review.

I then wanted to make a change and it didn't work like I wanted, so I said to discard it thinking it meant the subsequent change, but it seems to have deleted the entire example, which took about 30 minutes to write.

Is it gone forever?

The link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/v8/topic-requests/7285